# How to design a wrapper for memcached to allow for value larger than 1MB?

Tags: architecture, memcached, system

I was asked to design such a wrapper on a 15-minute segment of a Skype interview recently, and here's my design. I hope to receive more input on this design and if there is a better way to design it.

**Requirement:** A key-value store wrapper around Memcached (without any other data structure) that supports any size of value input, given Memcached's limitation of 1MB on value store.

**Proposal**:

1. Data structure: The same memcached
2. **`set(key, value)`**: say the input key is `memlarge`

   - Check if `sizeOf(value)` > 1MB, if yes, split the value into multiple binaries of size 1MB and `set` each of them into memcached, with the key scheme as follow:
   - Calculate a fixed-size hashcode of keys (e.g. use `md5`): `memlarge-1`, `memlarge-2`, ..., `memlarge-n`, say the results will be `ABC`, `DEF`, `GHI`
   - Concatenate these fixed-size hash codes and save it as the value of the original key, adding a suffix and prefix to it to prevent `get` method to misinterprete other values as an array of keys. So now `memlarge` is cached with value `prefixABCDEFGHIsuffix`, i.e. `get('memlarge')` will first return `prefixABCDEFGHIsuffix` (then more below)
3. **`get(key)`**:

   - Check if the result has the prefix and suffix for array
   - If yes, perform subsequent `get` operations to get the original value by delimiting the value `ABCDEFGH` by the hash code know size --> `get('ABC'), get('DEF'), get('GHI')` and eventually join the value to return to the user

**Critique of the proposal, follow up questions:**

1. Even with the suffix and prefix, there are still a (very small) chance that a random saved value possess this suffix & prefix. A fix then would be a length check of the remaining value after omitting prefix/suffix and a checksum (md5).
2. A value size 4MB will require 5 `get` operations. Is there a way to reduce that to 4?

   I think a solution to this would be using the idea of a linked list, but at a bit/byte-level implementation. A value chunk will end before the 1MB limit to save room for a "signal" that it requires another `get` (next node). The signal then could be design similarly to the "array" idea above.

Answer (score -1):

You have to question the original request. If you use memcache (out of process) to store a large file like an interview in skype, you will not only get a better performance but also a lower speed and performance; because as you may know everything that is going to put inside the memcache (out of process) needs to be serrialized and then when you read it from the cache it need to deserialize again. Every time you will try to get an 1 MB object from an out of process cache, it will consume significant CPU to build that object in memory.In your case, it is much faster if you load the interview into the memory whenever you need it.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question. The questions specifically asks that we design a wrapper for Memcached, using Memcached as the primary data storage, and it should work with values from a little bit over 1MB to gigabytes.